# how to prevent list item change realtime with onchange method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list that show some item, and they have Edit button beside the field, when you click the Edit button, it will show the modal that show name of the item where you can edit the name of the item. But the problem is when I try to change the name from the modal, the selected item from the list is changed too, before I click the save button.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-ride-myr8i?file=/src/App.js)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change the parent state from the modal, create a local state in modal and pass it on to the parent in the `onClose` callback and then change the state in parent.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-knuth-ik0ed

Comment: hello thank you for the answer, but can you give me an example about it?

Comment: updated my answer with the demo

Comment: thank youu!!, it works for my case